# Codeigniter: URL Helper with pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, pagination

I have issue with `uri_string()` and pagination with codeigniter

My Code is:

```
<?php echo anchor(site_url(uri_string().'/'.$item->url_product),$item->name_product);?>
```

My current url (page 2, `$config['per_page'] = 3`):

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/index.php/product/phone/page/3/
```

Run the code and get result (since I used pagination) for product URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/index.php/product/phone/page/3/lumia_950_xl
```

But, I want corecting that URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/index.php/product/phone/lumia_950_xl
```

I want eliminating `page/3/` in the output. How can I solve it?

---

In my head now

```
(if any 'page/3/' string at site_url())
{
   delete 'page/3/';
}
```

But I think there is another more easy way rather than using if statement like that, somebody? Thanks

---

OK finally I using replace statement, since no anybody give point here

```
$url_produk = uri_string();
$patern_url[0] = '(\/page\/\d)';
$patern_url[1] = '(\/page)';
$url_produk = preg_replace($patern_url, '', $url_produk);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your full pagination code from controller.

Comment: I dont have any trouble with pagination, it work with perfectly.

Comment: Pagination should stop working if you remove segment with page number from it.

Comment: Write your own pagination. Not clear whatsoever how you expect pagination to work if not using server side method but could also be done with javascript

Comment: can i suggest another way to set pagination?

Comment: @Angel ya sure, of course

Comment: k i wil give you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this code.
This is the i have done pagination in Codeigniter.

```
public function managecategory() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
        $parent = '0';
        $data['catdata'] = $this->b2bcategory_model->form_select($parent);
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        // bootstrap style for maintaining pagination
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "moderator/B2BCategory/managecategory";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->b2bcategory_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'first';
        $config['last_link'] = 'last';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->b2bcategory_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('moderator/managecategory', $data);
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');
    }
```